# Check if fields are empty before submitting jQuery for dynamic forms

Tags: jquery, validation, dynamic-forms

Good day.

I've number of dynamic forms, the total number of input fields is unknown,

I wanted to use a simple validation function such as:

```
function check_submit() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $(":submit").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

Since I'll be using the same function on number of different dynamic forms, each with its own "required fields" I want to be able to pass unknown number of classes which are required to be filled, the function should make sure that every field within that class is filled.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code :

```
$('form.classnameofelement').each(function(){
 if($(this).val().length != 0){
    // do somthing;
  }else{
    // do nothing;
  }
});
```

Let me know if any query.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't worked. it also seems that in order to make the each statement to run I'll need to bind the function to some action, which I prefer to avoid. I also failed to understand how can I declare this function at a "main.js" file and call it for each individual form by passing an unknown number of classes. Again thank you for your help.

Comment: And i've also took the liberty to change the selector to ('input.class')

Comment: Yes you can use input.class even, and you just need to put this each loop at form submit or onbutton click event. i think that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "required" attribute for browsers that support it. For those that don't you can do the following:

Update your inputs like this:

```
<input name="test1" required>
<input name="test2" required>
<input name="test3" required>
```

You can check if all the inputs have values like so:

```
var unfilled = $('[required]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().length === 0;
});

if (unfilled.length > 0) {
    // still unfilled inputs
    unfilled.css('border', '1px solid red');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've left this on for couple of days,
But today I've managed to create a working function

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
var empty_fields = [];
$(".chck").each(function(){
   if($(this).val().length !=0 ) {
       return;
   }else{
       empty_fields.push($(this).attr('name'));
       event.preventDefault();}
   });
if(empty_fields){
   alert(empty_fields);
}

});
```

I just need to make sure all the required fields have class="chck",
I hope someone will find it useful in the future.